# Windows Service not stopping, stuck at unsubscribing ews subscription

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, exchangewebservices, external

The service acts like a mail watcher on a mail box and is working fine after installing on a new server. But, while stopping it, i get this error message that the

> the service cannot accept control messages at this time

and all the ways to kill it didn't work.
It gets stuck at `removeSubscription()` as per the logs.

```
public static void Unsubscribe ()
{
     if (_ss.Id.Length>0){
              Logger.log("Reached Here");
             _connection.RemoveSubscription(_ss);
       }
}
```

Here `_ss` is the streamingSubscription, `_connection` is streamingSubscriptionConnection references

Can you tell me how to fix it?
P.S.: the same service works well on other server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually this function used to work really well on the previous server so had not used a try catch block to handle exceptions.

When i logged the exception, it turned out that it threw an error that the connection needs to be closed first. So changed the code to

```
_connection.close();
_connection.RemoveSubscription();
```

This solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may kill it like this.

**First Get the PID**
`sc queryex <servicename>`

**then Kill the pid with taskkill** 
`taskkill /pid <pid> /f`

within the Admin command prompt

Comment: Yes, i killed the service with powershell using the same approach.